# django model save error 'object has no attribute "field_id"

Tags: django, model, foreign-keys

I've got a simple django model with 2 optional fields. I'm getting an error when I try to save the model.

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    shipping = models.ForeignKey(ShippingRate, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.date_created:
            self.date_created = datetime.datetime.now()
        super(Cart, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Using a simple view to save a cart object, I get the following error -

```
'Cart' object has no attribute 'shipping_id'
```

It's the call to `super()` that's failing. I've had a look at the database and I've got the fields `'id'`, `'date_created'` and `'shipping_id'` on my table.

I'm managing my db with south, and I've tried removing, migrating and replacing fields but that doesn't work. It's a strange one - I expect I'm missing something obvious but I haven't spotted it yet..

UPDATE

I've tried removing the `save()` override, and even swapping out fields (then migrating with south). I swapped out the `shipping` field for a new `shipping_rate` field -

```
class Cart(models.Model):
    shipping_rate = models.ForeignKey(ShippingRate, blank=True, null=True)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This time I get the same error on save, only it's the date_created field that's causing it.

```
'Cart' object has no attribute 'date_created'
```

As before, I've had a glance at my (postgres) database, and I can see the 3 fields I expect - `id`, `shipping_rate_id`, and `date_created`.

UPDATE 2

OK, I've reduced my code to -

```
#models
class Cart(models.Model):
    shipping_rate = models.ForeignKey(ShippingRate, blank=True, null=True)
    modified = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)

    class Meta():
        app_label = 'cart'

#views
def add_to_cart(request):
    if 'cart' in request.session:
        cart = request.session['cart']
    else:
        cart = Cart()
    if not cart.pk:
        cart.save()
    return HttpResponse('ok')
```

And my traceback -

```
Traceback:
File "/Users/aidan/Environments/bbhq/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  111.                         response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/Users/aidan/Code/bbhq/bbhq/cart/views.py" in add_to_cart
  71.             cart.save()
File "/Users/aidan/Environments/bbhq/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save
  463.         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
File "/Users/aidan/Environments/bbhq/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py" in save_base
  551.                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
File "/Users/aidan/Environments/bbhq/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in _insert
  203.         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
File "/Users/aidan/Environments/bbhq/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in insert_query
  1575.     query.insert_values(fields, objs, raw=raw)
File "/Users/aidan/Environments/bbhq/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/subqueries.py" in insert_values
  170.                 value = getattr(obj, field.attname)

Exception Type: AttributeError at /cart/add_to_cart
Exception Value: 'Cart' object has no attribute 'shipping_rate_id'
```

Comment: Remove your `save()` method, change the DateTimeField to: `models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)`. See [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#datetimefield) for details. Not posting as an answer as I have no idea if that will fix your problem.

Comment: thanks @jpic. I made the changes but I get the same error :( it's the save method in models.Model that's failing.

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace of the Exception? It might be helpful

Comment: And the code of a minimal view that exhibits the problem.

Comment: I think because of south you should reset your south first delete your migration file then 'reset south' and 'convert_to_south app' . Then migrate ,it will probably work.

Comment: So in that code, which branch is executed - is the `cart` coming from the session? If so, how does it get there in the first place - is it possible you have an old pickled entity that dates from before you added those fields?

Comment: That's it! Thanks Daniel! I was working with an old pickled entity. I tried simplifying my view further and it works fine. (Do add a brief answer for me to accept & vote on).

Comment: @DanielRoseman - I'll vote on a simple 'see my comment' answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in the comment, there was an old entity in the session that was pickled before the new fields were added.